# При наведении на блок opacity делает прозрачным и текст

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, asp.net-mvc

Имеется вот такая View:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 imgEvents" style="background-image:url(../../Content/additional/m1.jpg); background-size:100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 335px; ">
  <div class="textinside">
     <h4 style="color:#ffffff;"><b>@ev.Title</b></h4>
     <a href="@Url.Action("EventDetails", "EventDetails", new { eventId = ev.Id }, null)" class="details" aria-hidden="true">DETAILS »</a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

при наведении на блок должна становиться прозрачной или затемняться картинка (задний фон), а текст должен оставаться каким и был.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`opacity` действует и на все внутренне содержимое.

Для решения проблемы можно поставить фон псевдоэлементу:

```css
.imgEvents {  
  height: 335px;
  position: relative;
}

.imgEvents:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  
  background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/200px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png); 
  background-size:100%; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
}

.imgEvents:hover:after {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-3 imgEvents" style="">
  <div class="textinside">
     <h4 style="color:#ffffff;"><b>@ev.Title</b></h4>
     <a href="@Url.Action("EventDetails", "EventDetails", new { eventId = ev.Id }, null)" class="details" aria-hidden="true">DETAILS »</a>
   </div>
 </div>
```